# ATBS: Character picture grid

Tags: python-3.x

I've been doing the Automate The Boring Stuff book projects and don't know what's wrong here, help me! 
My code outputs this:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
OOO...
.O.
```

Instead of:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

What's wrong??

CODE:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for y in range(len(grid[0])):
    for x in range(len(grid)):
        if x == 8:
            print(grid[x][y]+'\n', end='')
        else:
            print(grid[x][y], end='')
```

Comment: This code is correct, and when I run it locally, I get the correct output. What environment are you running this on? The only explanation is something that transform the output of 3 consecutive "." into something else.

Comment: I'm using Pycharm, but I'm new into this so I don't really know what happened, but thanks for answering!

Comment: try just saving the file - then use the OS terminal ("cmd" if you are on windows), navigate to the same folder where the file is saved (using the "cd" command), and just type "python <yourprogramname.py>"  - that is also a fundamental part of programming apprenticeship that tools like pycharm hide away from begginers - but without which, one can't actually have any idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong.
The code you posted correctly displays this:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

It would be more concise to handle the newline on its own:

```
for y in range(len(grid[0])):
    for x in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[x][y], end='')
        if x == 8:
            print('')
```

or better, just pull it out of the loop:

```
for y in range(len(grid[0])):
    for x in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[x][y], end='')
    print('')
```

Comment: I'm new into learning Python and I completely agree with you, your way it's more concise, thanks for answering!